# Getting the user's current location in iOS (no solution I've found is working)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to get the user's current location and to set the map view accordingly, I feel like I've tried everything and it's not working. Here's what I've got:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
//in viewdidload
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

float latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = latitude;
region.center.longitude = longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = SPAN_VALUE;
region.span.longitudeDelta = SPAN_VALUE;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"updated to location %f, %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

**Info.plist**

I have string values set for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and Privacy - Location Usage Description.

**Simulator**

Under "Debug" I have the coordinates for a custom location set, and this is what the location manager is supposed to retrieve, right? I've also checked the settings in the simulator and my app has location permissions for when the app is in use. However, when my map loads the view it's somewhere in the middle of the ocean which is not even close to the custom location.

I don't think the updateLocations method is even running, there's no NSLog output when I run the app. Any idea what's going on?

**Edit: The target build is for 8.4, since this is for a project I am not able to change it

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're doing everything out of order. Can you explain why you are setting the map view's region in `viewDidLoad`? That is way too soon, since it takes time to obtain the location. Also, if this is iOS 9, if you just want a one-time statement of the user's location, why are you not calling `requestLocation`?

Comment: It's for iOS 8 and has to be, I'll add that. And for the region I was just going off my teacher's code, that's where he sets it.

Comment: When you copy someone else's code, all the bugs in it become your responsibility.

Comment: Wow okay, sorry for basing the structure of my code off that of my professors. Thanks for your helpful and not at all over dramatic contribution.

Comment: But thanks Matt for pointing out where the code is going wrong, I'm going to change the structure so it has time to update.

Answer (score 0):

You're *almost* there. As mentioned in a few of the comments, you need to move the region updating code to **-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:**

In addition to that, make sure all of your info.plist keys are spelled exactly right. If they're not, the location will never update, and you won't get any error message. Also, check to make sure your mapView outlet is actually connected to a MKMapView in your XIB or Storyboard file.